# touchesBegan not called on UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextview, touchesbegan

I have created a simple test project with a single `UITextView` and the `touchesBegan` method in the view controller. For some reason, the `UITextView` is not responding to `touchesBegan`.

Things I have tried:

- `Alpha` is set to 1
- User interaction is enabled on the `view` and the `UITextView`
- `Delay Touch Down` is unchecked
- The `background` is set to a solid color

I found similar questions in several places, but none of the solutions have worked.

Comment: Why do you need `touchesBegan`?

Comment: I have an animation running on a button - if the user touches anything but the button, I'd like the animation to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it seems like others have successfully gotten `touchesBegan` to work on a `UITextField` in the past, nothing seems to be working now. Instead, I simply added `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and canceled the animation from there. Problem solved.